# Hiding and Showing default javascript alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, alert

How to hide and show the default Javascript `alert` in the same HTML Page.

For example:

In `function_one` I want to hide the Javascript default `alert`

```
function function_one() {
    //hide Javascript alert
}
```

In `function_two` I want to show the default Javascript which has been hidden in function_one

```
function function_two() {
    //show Javascript alert
}
```

Both Javascript functions are in the same HTML page.

Comment: What do you mean by "hide Javascript alert"? Which alert?

Comment: You mean the native `alert()` function?

Comment: Yes i want to hide and show window.alert() ;

Comment: You can't.. it can only be hidden by user interaction.

Comment: This question is really unclear. Why define 2 functions where you hide/show `alert()`? Just have, for example, a `click()` function showing an alert - otherwise it will not. Eg: `$('#test').click(function () { alert('Alert!'); });`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to prevent calls to `alert()` from being displayed, use the following code:

```
var defaultAlert = null;

function function_one() {
  if (defaultAlert === null) {
    defaultAlert = window.alert;
    window.alert = function() {};
  }
}

function function_two() {
  if (defaultAlert !== null) {
    window.alert = defaultAlert;
    defaultAlert = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :-) And always remember to define variables before using them to be sure about their scope ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can disable it by overriding its value with an empty function. You store the old value in a variable (`oldAlert`) and then restore it assigning the old value back to `window.alert`:

```
function function_one() {
    oldAlert = window.alert;
    window.alert = function() {};
}

function function_two() {
    window.alert = oldAlert;
}
```

Comment: Be careful with this approach, it messes up if you call `function_one()` twice...